# Определение времени изменения ячейки

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet

Добрый день!
В таблицах гугл с общим доступом нужно определить время последнего изменения ячейки и внести его в соседнюю. Это возможно?
Так же определить последнюю не пустую строку, по заданным параметрам в листе.
Возможно ли создать ленту событий? Суть задачи, есть строка, в который из списка будет выбираться действие, как только произошло изменение действия, нужно внести событие в ближайшую пустую строку в заданном массиве.
Прошу помочь, направить :)

Comment: Посмотрите этот вопрос и ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/653688/, этого, возможно, хватит для того,чтобы разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы поступил так:

- Назначить триггер событию "внесение изменений"
- Триггер запускает функцию, которая смотрит в ячейку и если ее значение отличается от предыдущего (и ее тоже где то надо хранить) то записать текущую дату в след ячейку.
- Не забудьте о параметрах времени, возможно для правильности придется искать функцию учитывающую часовой пояс (она есть, сейчас не помню имя)

На остальные вопросы отвечу отдельно как-нибудь )