# Узнать, где именно в Google SpreadSheet произошли изменения

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet

Есть таблица mainTable, которая имеет много листов. В эти листы автоматом собираются данные из других таблиц (через IMPORTRANGE): у одного человека - одна таблица, он вводит данные в нее, они тут же появляются в определенном листе таблицы mainTable. Вопрос, собственно, вот в чем: как отследить, в каком именно листе добавилась строка?
Нужно мне это для того, чтобы при появлении изменений в листе mainTable, эти изменения собирались в отдельном листе этой же таблицы (добавлялись новые строки).

Буду благодарен за любые подсказки.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю использовать триггер [onEdit(event)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#Simple)

При внесении изменений в документ, на указанном листе List1 в новой строке будет сделана запись вида

> List2  изменён Fri Jun 02 2017 11:20:17 GMT+0300 (MSK)

Код:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var mainTable = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1qrLAgHv1Dl5Gw0Jwafnfy9HaReJN2h5wYUlHrwNjCus"); // задаём id главной таблицы (mainTable)
  var sheet_with_changes = event.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName(); // находим лист с изменениями
  var mainTablesheet = mainTable.getSheetByName('List1'); // задаём лист (List1) главной таблицы, в котором будем отмечать изменения
  var lastRow = mainTablesheet.getLastRow(); // ищем последнюю пустую строку
  if (sheet_with_changes !== "List1") { // исключаем List1 из отслеживания изменений
    mainTablesheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1).setValue((sheet_with_changes) + " изменён " + (new Date())); // указываем на лист с изменениями и дату этих изменений
  }
}
```

[image: Создание триггера]
**(!)** При создании триггера выбирайте пункт *Изменение* второй по порядку (видимо, их два из-за проблемы перевода на русский).